# Shell Script to update the contents of a folder

Tags: perl, shell

I'm a beginner in Unix Shell Scripting and Perl Scripting.

I would like to have an example program that teaches me how to update a file contents on a directory.
The scenario is, there is a directory which has some n number of files.
Among those n number of files, m number of files have been modified.
I need to update the contents of the modified files in the directory.

Give me a simple shell script to do this.

Thanks and Regards,

Vijay

Comment: Is this for a job interview? Isn't it a bit dishonest to submit work that you didn't do yourself? How will you handle your daily duties if you are not qualified?

Comment: Dear xenoterracide and Ether, I'll tell you something. I'm not working in Perl Programming or a Unix shell scripting. My domain is completely different from the above two. I'm trying to Learn Unix and Linux by myself, Bcoz I want to change my current domain to something new, something really powerful. I'm working as a Mainframe sys admin, not as an application programmer. I just want to become a programmer. I appreciate that you added a comment on my post. It doesnt bother me, and I'm really happy to see ppl with no work to do except commenting on others...

Comment: @Invincible - (1) "Give me a simple shell script to do this" sounds really rude to most people; (2) There's a major difference between "I tried X, Y and Z and it didn't work in A, B and C ways, please help me fix the problem" and "Do my work for me". Your question looks and sounds like the latter.

Comment: @DVK: Fine DVK. As you said, I should have told you that, I tried something and it didn't work out. If possible, kindly take a look at my second question. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Invincible: I'm glad to hear that. We get a lot of "plz send me the codes" questions here, people trying to cheat on their schoolwork and fake their way through job interviews, so when we see "give me a script" without attempting to explain what they have tried so far (which would help demonstrate a genuine attempt to learn and solve a specific problem), it's not difficult to assume the worst.  You may also find this link interesting: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Perl**

- To Update a File content see **[perlfaq5](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html)**, you will find lot of information regarding **File manipulation**.You will get a lot of **examples** of **file manipulations**.
- Getting **File** or Dir **Statistics** see perl built in function **[stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html)**.
- For **Traverse** a directory tree, see
  **[File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.1/lib/File/Find.pm)**

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with find like this:

```
find your_directory -newermt time_of_last_check -exec modify_script.sh {} \;
```

where:

your_directory is the directory where you have the files.

time_of_last_check is when you last ran this command

modify_script.sh is the program that you will run to modify the files, it should take one argument, and that is the filename to modify.

Comment: Thank you very much.. A bit helpful. Took too long to understand what exactly it is,..